# SelectedItem binding works in UWP but not in ios

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I have a `ListView` and am binding to the `SelectedItem` property:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" IsVisible="{Binding Expanded}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <!-- not relevant code -->
</ListView>
```

When I run it on UWP, my `SelectedItem` property in my view model gets set when I select an item in the list. But not in ios. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a work around?

Comment: Can you please share your code in your view-model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple demo and it works on my side. Here is the code:

```
<ListView x:Name="testListView"
        Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}" SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then in your view-model(viewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
class testViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private testViewModel _yourSelectedItem { get; set; }

    public testViewModel YourSelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _yourSelectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _yourSelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("YourSelectedItem");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And in the MainPage, set the `BindingContext = new testViewModel();`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<testViewModel> myModels = new ObservableCollection<testViewModel>();

    testViewModel model;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myModels.Add(new testViewModel { Name = "age" });
        myModels.Add(new testViewModel { Name = "gender" });
        myModels.Add(new testViewModel { Name = "name" });

        testListView.ItemsSource = myModels;

        BindingContext = new testViewModel();
    }
}
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you.